# how can add row to a table with a field that referenced to another table in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new in django.
I have this two classes in my models :

```
class bugtraq(models.Model):
    bugId=models.CharField(max_length=20 , verbose_name="ID" )
    remote=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    local=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class References(models.Model):
    title=models.TextField()
    bugId=models.ManyToManyField(bugtraq)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to add a row in my References table in my views; I write it in this way:

```
 ref_row=References(title="Mozilla Firefox", bugId="12345")
 ref_row.save()
```

and I got this error:'bugId' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.
how can I add this row to my table?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
bug= bugtraq.objects.get(id="12345")
ref_row = References(title="Mozilla Firefox")
ref_row.save()
ref_row.bugId.add(bug)
```

To set `ManyToMany` relationship, you need to do `.add()`.